# PostgreSQL using search_path for multi tenancy

Tags: postgresql, jpa, multi-tenant, java-ee-7

I am developing a multi-tenancy web application using PostgreSQL as database, because of its support for schemas in one database instance. But I am stuck on a problem, setting up the search_path for a tenant.

I am using JavaEE 7 with Wildfly 8.2.0. I have created an MultiTenantConnectionProvider which uses a DataSourceConnectionProvider loading the configured DataSource.

The method for retrieveing a connection set the search_path to the given tenantId:

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantId) throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = getAnyConnection();
    try
    {
        con.createStatement().execute("SET search_path = '" + tenantId + "'");
        LOG.info("Using " + tenantId + " as database schema");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new HibernateException("Could not alter connection for specific schema");
    }
    return con;
}
```

For first tests I am returning always the same tenantId "customer1".

On Postgres I have created one user, which has its own database and one schema "customer1". I have an entity `user` defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String gender;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte[] password;
    private String passwordResetToken;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte[] salt;
...
}
```

I have created the table in the schema "customer1". No w my problem is that the select statement for table user is returning an other user-table. I have to explicitly set the schema name with the table, otherwise I query the wrong table.

The statement:

```
select * from user; -> current_user name: user1
```

returns:

```
| current_user name |
--------------------
| "skedflex"        |
```

The statement:

```
select * from customer1.user;
```

returns:

```
| id | username | firstname | lastname | ... |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | johnnie  | John      | Doe      | ... |
```

It would be no option to use the schema name in the query, cause that value is determined during runtime and I am using JPA. So there is no way to insert the schema name during runtime query execution.

I have expected, that the search_path is sufficient for querying data.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-alteruser.html You can set the search_path *per user*

Comment: Can't you hook the connection pool so it invokes a callback when acquiring a connection? Also, you've got logging in place: does the logging show your SET is actually run? If you enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` do you see the expected statement run? Try setting a `log_line_prefix` in `postgresql.conf`….

Comment: I have tested this alos with pgAdmin 3, first running the command `set search_path = 'customer1';` and then trying to select the user with id = 1: `select * from user where id = 1;` but it gives me the wrong result mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem with my setup. 
In PostgreSQL `user` is a keyword and tables with this name cannot be created, except user is escaped with quotes: `"user"`. I have changed the table name to `user_account` and the queries work as expected.